# Text "Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed" in edit post notice should be more visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, dark-mode

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) in Dark Mode, when clicking on a post to edit it, I'm greeted with this message (because I don't have full editing privileges):

[image]

That's not the problem.  The text is too light, too faint.  I did some digging, and found that in Dark Mode, the text is colored with `color:  #cfd2d6`, or a light, silver-gray.  But in normal (Light) mode, the text is `color: #3c4146`, or just black:

[image]

Could we make it so the same black color applies to both?  On that yellowish background, in a mode that dark, the silvery-gray text is too light.

Here is a shot of what the black color looks like in Dark Mode:

[image]

It's a small adjustment, but it would be more comfortable.  Heck, you could make it even darker.  It'd be more readable, especially in Dark Mode.

Comment: Since Dark Mode is SO only, I'm going to move this to MSO, which is where all of the Dark Mode bugs are.

Comment: @Catija But isn't Meta SE where you should request software/design changes?  Also, this is no longer [tag:status-review].

Comment: No. If the requests are site-specific, they should be made on the child meta of the site that's impacted. MSE should be used only for issues that impact two or more sites.

Comment: @Ollie This hasn't been fixed yet. I checked with my SockPuppet account. So it shouldn't be [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: @10Rep See my edit... when it got migrated, the status tag from MSE disappeared, so I added it back. They're not asking to make it status-complete, they're asking to add the status review tag... which I did. :)

Comment: This has been reported yesterday, but the post has been deleted for whatever reason: [New user edit notice is nearly unreadable in dark mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401914/4642212).

Comment: @user4642212 Was it deleted by the author, by users voting to delete, by a moderator, or by the Community user? If the last, what does it say as the deletion reason in the timeline?

Comment: @gparyani It was deleted by the post author 2 minutes after submission. See [timeline screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Djtm.png).